# Using class from .groovy file located in another folder (Gradle)

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have this **build.gradle** file which works fine:

```
class Utils  {
  def doit(){
    println "hi from utils"
  }
}

task hello << {
  def utils = new Utils()
  utils.doit();
}
```

If I move the class/.groovy file to a sub-folder like this:

```
test
 -> groovy
     -> Utils.groovy
 -> build.gradle
```

and modify the build.gradle file to this:

```
dependencies {
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'groovy', include: '*.groovy')
}

task hello << {
  def utils = new Utils()
  utils.doit();
}
```

The Utils class can no longer be found:

```
...unable to resolve class Utils
```

I assume that the subfolder **groovy** should be added as an import/entry on the classpath/dependency in the .gradle file. I have read these pages:

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

but have not been able to find any docs that describes how to import .groovy files in the .gradle file. What page am I missing that describes this simple functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change your build.gradle to simply be

```
task hello << {
  def utils = new Utils()
  utils.doit();
}
```

Then instead of

```
test
 -> groovy
     -> Utils.groovy
 -> build.gradle
```

move the `Utils.groovy` file to `buildSrc/src/main/groovy` like so:

```
test
 -> buildSrc
     -> src
         -> main
             -> groovy
                 -> Utils.groovy
 -> build.gradle
```

and gradle should pick it up automatically.

See the section "41.4. Build sources in the buildSrc project" in [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html) for further information.

Comment: That works. As a result a .gradle and build folder is created with jar, reports, classes. Is all this necessary to import a class in the .gradle file? And is it possible to specify this path at another location?

Comment: Yes, all of this is necessary. (But then, how much effort is it?) Remember that Groovy is a compiled language, so the class has to be compiled and put on the build script's class path _before_ the build script can be evaluated. Classes have to go under `buildSrc` or into an external Jar. Additional build scripts can go anywhere and can be included with `apply from: "path/to/script"`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser and how do you handle imports? when I import stuff in buildscript{} it works in build.gradle, but I get unable to resolve class XXX exceptions when trying to use the dependency in the custom classes.

Comment: @sydd that sounds like you need to post a question ;-)

Comment: I figured it out, the solution is that there needs to be a build.gradle file in the buildSrc  folder that holds the dependencies for the build script.