# Using groovy classes within Gradle build

Tags: groovy, build, gradle

I'm trying to run a Groovy class from within my build.gradle file. I'm following the direction in [the use guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html) however I get an error.

The build file is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

  main {
    java {
      srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/java"]
    }
    groovy {
      srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/groovy"]
    }
  }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.0', files(....)
    }

    task fooTask << {
        groovyClass groovyClass = new groovyClass()
        groovyClass.foo()
    }
```

The groovy class is very simple:

```
    public class groovyClass {

            public void foo() {
                    println 'foo'
            }
    }
```

However when I try to run **gradlew compile fooTask** I get the following error:

**unable to resolve class groovyClass**

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: I already tried the solution suggested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580057/using-class-from-groovy-file-located-in-another-folder-gradle) but the issue still persists

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add the class to `buildSrc` if you want to reference it from the build (and not in a simple Exec task).  Given this directory structure:

```
|-buildSrc
|    |- src
|        |- main
|            |- groovy
|                |- GroovyClass.groovy
|- build.gradle
```

Where `GroovyClass.groovy` is:

```
class GroovyClass {
    void foo() {
        println 'foo'
    }
}
```

And `build.gradle` is:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1'
}

task fooTask << {
    GroovyClass g = new GroovyClass()
    g.foo()
}
```

Then, running `gradle fooTask` gives the output:

```
$ gradle fooTask
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE
:fooTask
foo

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.604 secs
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to change where gradle looks for the classes, so instead of buildSrc/src/main/groovy it will look for it at src/main/groovy?

Comment: Not that I know of. To run the build it will have first had to run the build, so you get a chicken and egg situation. Not sure if a symbolic link in buildSrc to the groovy file in SRC will work if the file is required in both and you don't want to maintain two files?

Comment: gradle will fetch your groovy sources in `srcDirs` from your build.gradle. Put whatever path you would like to be a gradle source directory and you're good to go.