# Use Java class in Gradle build script

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have a Gradle build script which has to instantiate a Java class in a Task and call a method on the created object. Currently, I have the following:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile files("libs/some.library.jar")
}

task A << {

    def obj = new some.library.TestClass()
    obj.doSomething()

}
```

The problem is that the class `some.library.TestClass()` is not found. I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905608/using-groovy-classes-within-gradle-build) about how to use Groovy classes in Gradle, but I need my Java class to come from an external JAR file. How can I add a jar to the build source? It seems that the `dependencies` block doesnt do what I expect it to do. Can anyone give me a hint in the right direction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The dependency `compile files("libs/some.library.jar")` is added as a project dependency not as the script dependency itself. What You need to do is to add this dependency in script's `classpath` scope.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
   dependencies {
      classpath files("libs/some.library.jar")
   }
}

task A << {
    def obj = new some.library.TestClass()
    obj.doSomething()
}
```

Now it should work.

Comment: This also works in Android Studio, although you don't need the 'apply plugin' line, which it will complain conflicts with the android plugin, and 'buildscript' needs to be all lower case.