# How to add script dependencies to gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I would like to use some library in Gradle build tasks and wrote:

```
buildScript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('lib/matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar')
    }
}
```

according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26314875/258483

Unfortunately, it does not work with error:

> Could not find method buildScript() for arguments
>   [build_dequiq884i95u7leo8gt9c8xk$_run_closure1@5a63dd5b] on root
>   project

How to fix and why it was answered as working method in referenced answer?

Comment: `buildscript` should be in lowercase read comments in answer

Comment: Error disappeared, but classes from JAR are unusable...

Comment: check this it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329872/how-to-add-external-jar-files-to-gradle-build-script

Comment: I don't understand what is it there? Why should I do that hacking? Why can't I just import required jar or plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change buildScript to buildscript

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('lib/matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar')
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare a task dependency ? For example, I have a task which publish a message to RabbitMQ Broker so I need RabbitMQ Java driver to do so.

Comment: I know how to define task in gradle. You will get more information on net. In that you can write your own logic. For basic you can start from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_tasks.htm