# Use a java class in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hi Maybe this is a foolish question but i am not much familiar with groovy and gradle and can't get the exact answer.

```
  public class Config{
   public static final String APPLICATION_ID="com.app.dracula";
   public static final int VERSION_CODE=1;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME="1.0.0";
}
```

I have class like above . Can i use this class in `build.gradle` to assign the all fields(Watch out the fields names).

I know i can create `BuildConfigField` from a `properties` file which i am doing right now . But out of curiosity is there a way to use a .java class or interface in `build.gradle`?   Can i achieve something like .

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId Config.APPLICATION_ID
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode Config.VERSION_CODE
    versionName Config.VERSION_NAME
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Don't Confused by above code this is just an metaphor of what i want to achieve .

Comment: The way you are trying is not possible as JAVA classes are yet not compiled and hence you can not use java class variables or objects.
You should initiate a class within Gradle file.
For eg:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26314875/3594268
Then maybe you can use its variables.
NOTE:-Not tested.

Comment: Thats seems a fair reason for why i can't do that . Thx .

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

Comment: I'd argue doing it the opposite way around would make more sense. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java

Comment: Thx Michael  I am the same method right now . Are you satisfied with @ Abhinav Aggarwal's Comment ?

Comment: if you just want to access those variable as constants then there is no need for creating a class, just store them in gradle.properties and and configure them in build.gradle like this    `buildConfigField("String", "APP_ID","\"${APP_ID}\"")`

Comment: @AshishSharma  Yeah thats what i am doing right now . But requirement is kind of having a single file which have only the configurations and nothing else . So i dropped `gradle.properties` and i created my own properties file . And its working fine. But i was just curious about using a `.java` class or interface.

Comment: ok, yeah creating your own .properties file is a good choice. Never thought about using .java, i'll dig into it, if I find something useful i'll let you know.